# Verbs of motion with prefix "у-" and "при-"

Tags: вид, motion-verbs

I am currently learning how to use verbs of motion with the prefixes `у-` and `при-` to express that someone *departs from* or *arrives at* a certain location.

However, I struggle with the following sentence from a textbook:

> Каждый раз я _____ (1) в новый город и скоро _____ (2) обратно, в Волгоград.

My attempt to fill the gaps is as follows:

1. **Choice of verbs:** Given options are *walking*, *driving* or *flying*. I figured that either `е́хать` or `е́здить` would fit best to express "travelling" in a more general sense:

   - `уе́хать` / `уе́здить` (*to depart*)
   - `прие́хать` / `прие́здить` (*to arrive*)
2. **Choice of direction:** When it comes to the correct prefixes, I struggle for the first time. For (1) I'm pretty sure that the prefix should be `при-`, since the person *arrives in a new town every time*. **In cloze (2), however, would one use `у-` or `при-`?** Does the person soon *leave* to return to Volgograd (`у-`) or does the person soon *come back* to Volgograd (`при-`)?
3. **Choice of aspect:** Another challenge is picking the right aspect, i.e. `е́хать` or `е́здить`. I learned that when something happens *repeatedly*, I'd rather use `е́здить`. Though the person travels multiple times (`каждый раз`), I feel `е́хать` is more suitable here. Although traveling multiple times, each incident in itself is closed (i.e. perfected verb).

So my educated guess would be:

> Каждый раз я **прие́хала** (1) в новый город и скоро **уе́хала** (2) обратно, в Волгоград.

Since I have nowhere to validate my guess, I hope someone on here - maybe a native speaker - can explain what the correct answer is in terms of prefixes and which aspect to use.

Comment: the verbs **ездить, плавать, лазать, прыгать, бЕгать, пОлзать, пАдать** (to name a few, don't have a comprehensive list) don't exist with prefixes **у-** and **при-** and in fact with most prefixes, of the last three two do receive these and most other prefixes but change the stress **при-/убегАть, при-/уползАть** while the 3d receives them with the stress shift **припадАть** etc. to the exclusion of the prefix **у-**, **ездить** in most prefixed forms not only changes stress but also its base into **езжАть**

Comment: Verb choice here depends on context. Without context, "при-/у-" would be correct. Ex: "Каждый раз я приезжаю в новый город и скоро уезжаю обратно, в Волгоград". But if the context is point of origin/return, then verbs are reversing. Ex: "Вы не скучаете по своей семье?" - "Каждый раз я уезжаю в новый город и скоро приезжаю обратно, в Волгоград." ("Do you miss your family?" - "Every time I go to a new city, but soon return back, to Volgograd.")

Comment: I would say this phrase is very innatural to me. I wonder if the textbook was written by some native Russian-speaker or some foreign person who studied Russian as foreign language himself.... "Каждый раз" and "скоро" just do not fit one another. "Каждый раз [как, когда] я приезжаю (или приеду) в новый город" - is quite a good phrase with repetitive/habit aspect. "Я скоро уеду обратно" is equaly goos non-repetitive "perfect tense" phrase, kind a "soon i'll be gone back home". But together they just do not fit at all! There are idiomatic ways to express repetitive going back.

Comment: But they would be different. So I quite understand your confusion - it is really a hard choice you are to make, when two parts of a sentence fight one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Каждый раз я приезжаю/прилетаю__ (1) в новый город и скоро уезжаю/улетаю ___ (2) обратно, в Волгоград.

1 Choice of verbs: you can travel by car, train or fly. Приезжать/прилетать, уезжать/улетать.

2.You chose directions correctly, because there's a certain opposition: come and go
Ездить is ok without prefix,  with prefixes we use приезжать, уезжать.
If there's no opposition you can use приехать обратно /приезжать обратно.

> Я всегда с радостью приезжаю обратно /возвращаюсь (return). Вчера она прилетела назад в Волгоград.

3 Aspect. For repeated actions we use imperfective (каждый раз), present time.